# Android - How to open the default phone app screen in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-settings

I'm looking for a way to open the "default phone app dialog" in Marshmallow programmatically - I assume that I'm looking for the intent that should be called, something similar to `android.provider.Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT` that I use to set my app as the default sms app.

Your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution - [TelecomManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html#ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER) with a sample usage

```
Intent intent = new Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER);
intent.putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME,
     getActivity().getPackageName());
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: pop up window not coming , I ma using Android v 6.0.1